# Узнать MAC-адрес, зная IP-адрес компьютера

Tags: delphi, ip-address, mac-address

Зная IP адрес нужно узнать MAC адрес компьютера.

Comment: Задача сформулирована слишком общо. Конкретизируйте. Нужео узнать свой мак? Или чужой? Компьютер в каких сетях располагаются? Админские права на локальной машине есть? И т.п.

Comment: Сеть локальная. MAC чужой машины. Админ права есть.

Answer (score 2):

На делфи не знаю, а так есть команда arp -a

Она печатает соответствия MAC и IP из arp таблицы. Поэтому можно узнать MAC-и только локального (до маршрутизатора) сегмента сети. Свой MAC она не печатает.

**UPD**

Никто в форуме видимо не знает точно. Немного погуглил и может быть это окажется Вам полезным.

[http://www.unix.com/programming/143063-siocgarp-display-entire-arp-table.html](http://)

Сразу скажу - это из Linux, а у Вас видимо Винда. Но все равно можно покопать в направлении аналога для ioctl SIOCGARP.